# SimpleSAMLphp on Mac

Tags: php, apache, macos, saml

Using Mac OS X 10.6.7, preinstalled Apache2 and PHP.

I'm trying to install SimpleSAMLphp for authentication. The documentation describes how to install simpleSAMLphp using a VirtualHost, but other ways are described very insufficiently.

Can someone describe how to install SimpleSAMLphp without using a VirtualHost?

Answer (score 2):

The configuration line you need is this:

> `Alias /simplesaml "/Users/andreas/simplesamlphp/www/"`

in your Apache configuration, and if you are not using vhosts, you put it in the general config file. Put it close to DocumentRoot.

If you do not want to touch apache configuration files, you could simulate the same with a symlink.

> `cd <webroot>`
>
> `ln -s "/Users/andreas/simplesamlphp/www/" simplesaml`

I'd reccomend that you join the [SimpleSAMLphp mailinglist](http://simplesamlphp.org/lists) to ask questions about simpleSAMLphp.

Comment: Because of where I have MAMP installed I had to use the configuration 

Alias /simplesaml "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/simplesamlphp/www/"

The config file to edit is at /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf Also note that you have to restart MAMP for changes to the config file to take effect.